# Graphics issue with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-artifacts

I'm having a bit of a graphics issue with my Google Chrome. I recently downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 on VMware and downloaded Chrome from the terminal. The problem is that I have all this weird graphical issues, but only in Chrome web browser. Is there a way I can fix this? I want to use Chrome rather than Firefox.

When trying to post on Reddit:

[image: When trying to post on Reddit]

When trying to search on Google:

[image: When trying to search on Google]

Corner of this website:

[image: Corner of this website]

Answer (score 12):

Found a workaround for this:

chrome://flags

Search for "Vulkan"

Change from "default" to "Enabled"

Restart Chrome

Comment: But why does Ubuntu 22.04 cause this when Ubuntu 21.10 did not?

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 for about 6 months and never had this issue. Now I'm getting it a lot! Started this week. Enabling Vulkan did not solve it to me. Actually, setting it to "disabled" is working better. I have RX 580 graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.
Enabling Vulkan solves the graphics issue on chromium-based browsers.
But the problem with this is that any web app that requires webGL is not working.

here's an example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes

[screenshot with Vulkan enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmhqG.png)

[screenshot without Vulkan (on Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw3ww.png)

Right now my best solution is to disable 3D acceleration in browser settings, though this comes at a cost of performance in 3D objects but you'll be able to see everything in the website correctly.

Comment: Do you know why this happens in 22.04 but not in 21.10? What changed?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my nvidia driver from 525 to 535 solved the problem.
I just ran

```sh
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

to upgrade to the latest tested/recommended drivers.

You can always check for available drivers using `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` or `software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4` before updating. <sup>[also see Ubuntu docs](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation)</sup>

Disabling 3D acceleration in Chrome also worked for me, but it made a lot of websites quite laggy and slow.